# Indexing JavaScript with anonymous function gives an error: "Undefined"

Tags: javascript, function

My problem is to retreive 'A', 'B', 'C' or 'D', if the first letter of my passed string s, belongs to {a,e,i,o,u} or {b,c,d,f,g} or {h,j,k,l,m} or other remaining, respectively.
I am trying to achieve the same like this:

```
function getLetter(s){
        let letter = 'ABCD'[findIndex(s[0])];
        return letter;
    }
function findIndex(t){
        var a = Number.parseInt("aeioubcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz".indexOf(t)/5);
        //console.log(a);
        if (a<3){
            return a;
        }
        else{
            return 3;
        }
    }
```

And it worked. But when I tried to reduce the number of lines using an anonymous function, I can't get my function executed. I know I have a silly error, as I new to programming. What is wrong with my code?
with something like this:

```
let getLetter = s =>'ABCD'[function(){
        var a = Number.parseInt("aeioubcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz".indexOf(s[0])/5);
        console.log("anonymous function executed");
        if (a<3){
            return a;
        }
        else{
            return 3;
        }
    }]
My output is: undefined
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first example, you called your `findIndex` method, but in the second one, you just defined the `function`, without calling it.

You have to solutions to fix it:

1. to use **IIFE** (**Immediately Invoked Function Expression**):

where you define and call your method, like what your trying to do here, check the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE).

```js
let getLetter = s =>'ABCD'[(function(){
        var a =     Number.parseInt("aeioubcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz".indexOf(s[0])/5);
        console.log("anonymous function executed");
        if (a<3){
            return a;
        }
        else{
            return 3;
        }
    })()];
console.log(getLetter('e'))
```

2. define `findIndex` as a seperated `function`:

Which makes your code clearer.

```js
let getLetter = s =>'ABCD'[_findIndex(s)];
    
let _findIndex = letter => {
    var a =         Number.parseInt("aeioubcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz".indexOf(letter[0])/5);
        console.log("anonymous function executed");
        if (a<3){
            return a;
        }
        else{
            return 3;
        }
    
};
console.log(getLetter('e'))
```

Comment: Oh yes! I had actually implemented the second snippet though. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's because in your original code you are executing `findIndex()`, but in your second code you are simply using the anonymous function itself as index, you are not executing it.

```js
let getLetter = s =>'ABCD'[function(){
        var a = Number.parseInt("aeioubcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz".indexOf(s[0])/5);
        console.log("anonymous function executed");
        if (a<3){
            return a;
        }
        else{
            return 3;
        }
    }()]
console.log(getLetter("a"));
```

Answer (score 0):

in your case you only write the function defenition. to run a function you need to add (). so just add () after the defenition.

```js
let getLetter = s =>'ABCD'[function(){
        var a = Number.parseInt("aeioubcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz".indexOf(s[0])/5);
        console.log("anonymous function executed");
        if (a<3){
            return a;
        }
        else{
            return 3;
        }
    }()];
    
console.log(getLetter('a'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You just pass the reference of function, you didn't execute it. you can add `()` immediately after the function ends to run it like this:

```js
let getLetter = s =>'ABCD'[function(){
        var a = Number.parseInt("aeioubcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz".indexOf(s[0])/5);
        console.log("anonymous function executed");
        if (a<3){
            return a;
        }
        else{
            return 3;
        }
    }()]
    
    console.log(getLetter('test'));
```

But I highly recommend not to do that, because it's harder to read, understand, maintain, and develop when time passes.
the more important than decrease code lines is it to be human-readable, like `Martin Fowler` say

> Any fool can write code that a computer can understand. Good programmers write code that humans can understand.